# SQL Query - listing Average Age of Chapter Members

Tags: mysql, distinct, average

I need a list of the 'Average Age' of the Members for each of 90 Chapters.
There are 3 tables: Members, Chapters, Chapt_Memb (maps Members<-to->Chapters).

This produces a single answer, the Average Age of ALL Members of ALL Chapters:

```
SELECT distinct Chapters.ID, Chapters.Name, avg( floor(datediff(curdate(),Members.dob) / 365.242199)) as AvgAge
    FROM Members,Chapters,Chapt_Memb
    WHERE Chapters.ID=Chapt_Memb.chapt_id and Members.ID=Chapt_Memb.memb_id
    ORDER by Chapters.ID
```

Returns: "ID-1, Name=Wilmington, AvgAge=48.275"

How do I get a list of each Chapter with its respective AvgAge?

Comment: you need to use grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lose the distinct and group by id and name

```
SELECT Chapters.ID, Chapters.Name, avg(floor(datediff(curdate(),Members.dob) / 365.242199)) as AvgAge
FROM Members,Chapters,Chapt_Memb
WHERE Chapters.ID=Chapt_Memb.chapt_id and Members.ID=Chapt_Memb.memb_id
GROUP BY Chapters.ID, Chapters.Name
ORDER by Chapters.ID
```

Comment: Yes (sorry, I'm new to the "asking questions" part of this)!